# formtastic check_boxes using collection not saving checked items in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I know this was supposed to be fixed in Formtastic 2.0 but for some reason, this isn't working for me.

```
          <%= f.input :gender, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => ["Male", "Female", "Unisex"] %>
```

Whenever I go back and check it, the items is always unchecked again.  It never appears as selected.  I know Justin French commented about it [here](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/commit/d2c4ff73d9079f07f53efd193316d283bc332b7d), but I am not sure what it means or how that can help me fix the problem.

I am saving gender as a string in the User model if it makes a difference.

I am also using it with formtastic-bootstrap 1.1.1

Thank you!