# formtastic with spree check_boxes using collection not saving checked items in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I am using formtastic-2.2.1, Spree 1.3 and Rails 3.2.18.

This in my form input that I am having issues with:

```
  = f.input :collection_products, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false, :collection => Spree::Product.order("name").all
```

The issue I am having is when I create a new collection_page and hit edit previously selected items are unselected in the edit form, all the other inputs are working as expected.

I've tried it with a simple collection, like `:collection => ["x", "y", "z"]`

ie:. If I select "x", "y" and try to edit it, they are no longer selected.

Collection Page model:

```
class CollectionPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spree_products, :class_name => Spree::Product
```

and added `belongs_to :spree_collection_pages`to product_decorator.rb

I'm having the exact same issue as [formtastic check_boxes using collection not saving checked items in edit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727890/formtastic-check-boxes-using-collection-not-saving-checked-items-in-edit-form)

Would be awesome if someone can help out!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by using simple_form instead and did the following on my form:

```
= f.association :spree_products, :collection => Spree::Product.order("name").all, :prompt => "Choose products for this collection"
```